# Get References to Powershell's Stream Objects?

Tags: powershell

I am interested in getting .NET object references for the different streams that come with a Powershell host (stdin, plus the 5 output streams debug, info, error, etc.) I am interested in passing these to custom .NET types which will NOT be cmdlets... just .NET types that expect to use 5 output streams and 1 input stream.

I have spent lots of time googling and msdning and I just can't seem to find information about these streams beyond the cmdlets that read/write them.

If this is not possible, then a link to some related documentation would make for an answer.

**Update**

Thanks for the feedback so far, and sorry for the delay in making it back to this question.

@CharlieJoynt the idea here is that I will be using PowerShell as an entry point for a number of custom .NET types. These are types that will also be imported into other class libraries and EXEs so they cannot be PowerShell-specific. Anything that does host the types will, however, provide streams for info/log/error/etc output (instead of choosing a specific logging framework like log4net).

@PetSerAl I am not sure what an XY question is? If my update doesn't add the clarity you are looking for, can you clarify ( :P ) what the gap is?

Thanks again for the feedback so far, folks.

Comment: Look like XY question for me. What are you really trying to achieve? And why do you think you need references to PowerShell Stream objects for that?

Comment: Yeah, a little clarity here will help with what looks like quite an interesting question. For example, are you trying to solve this problem *within* PowerShell (e.g. logging different streams to different log files) or in the environment *around* PowerShell (e.g. when writing a custom host).

Comment: @Paul, an XY question is discussed here on the "meta" site for this forum:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to intercept data written to certain streams by using the `Register-ObjectEvent` cmdlet.

> **Register-ObjectEvent**
>
> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849929.aspx
>
> The **Register-ObjectEvent** cmdlet subscribes to events that are
>   generated by .NET Framework objects on the local computer or on a
>   remote computer. When the subscribed event is raised, it is added to
>   the event queue in your session. To get events in the event queue, use
>   the Get-Event cmdlet.
>
> You can use the parameters of **Register-ObjectEvent** to specify
>   property values of the events that can help you to identify the event
>   in the queue. You can also use the Action parameter to specify actions
>   to take when a subscribed event is raised and the Forward parameter to
>   send remote events to the event queue in the local session.

In my case I had created a new `System.Diagnostics.Process` object as **$Process**, but before starting that process I registered some event handlers, which exists as Jobs, e.g.

```
$StdOutJob = Register-Object-Event -InputObject $Process `
  -EventName OutputDataReceived -Action $ScriptBlock
```

...where `$ScriptBlock` is a pre-determined script block that handles the events coming from that stream. Within that script block, the events are accessible via some built-in variables:

> The value of the **Action** parameter can include the **$Event**,
>   **$EventSubscriber**, **$Sender**, **$EventArgs**, and **$Args**
>   automatic variables, which provide information about the event to
>   the Action script block.

So your ScriptBlock could take `$EventArgs.Data` and *do something* with it.

Disclaimer: I have *not* used this method to try to intercept all the streams you mention, just `OutputDataReceived` and`ErrorDataReceived`.

Comment: When I have some down time I'm going to dig into this Register-ObjectEvent business and see if I can accomplish the task with it. If so I'll post what I did.